# Single word alternative to "overvalue"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Generally speaking, *attach too much significance to [something]* can be replaced *overvalue*, but that doesn't sit well with me in certain contexts.

For example, suppose I reached some conclusion after considering various factors, but it turns out later that I accorded too much weight to "Factor X" (causing me to reach the *wrong* conclusion).

*"I attached/ascribed/assigned/etc. too much significance to X"* conveys exactly what I want to say. I can't explain why *"I overvalued X"* doesn't cut it for me - that's just the way it is.

Words such as *overstate, overplay, overemphasise* all seem to imply I focused too much on *X* in a debate attempting to defend my (erroneous) conclusion. And *overestimate* implies mistakenly thinking *X* was *bigger* than it really was (rather than just "more important than it should be").

Ideally, I'm looking for *"I xxxx'ed X"*, but even *"I xxxx'ed the importance of X"* would do.

Comment: ... _overestimated the significance of_ ... is a permutation you don't seem to have stated, but the expression you mention first works well for me.

Comment: Injudicious is possible, but is more to do with judgement than overvalue.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: I might (just about) have formed an *injudicious opinion*, but I can't see how any word based on that concept could be used to describe my erroneous treatment of *Factor X*.

Comment: If *refragatory* ("Disposed to controvert or refute", OED) weren't obsolete, it would give an easy solution; eg “I subrefragatorized X”.

Comment: No it wouldn't.

Answer (score 4):

You can *overrate* something or *overrate* the importance of something.

[Overrate](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/overrate):

> have a higher opinion of (someone or something) than is deserved

Answer (score 4):

How about *overweight*?

> [***overweight***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overweight) :*To place excessive weight or emphasis on; to overestimate the importance of*

Comment: I can't deny that this one *should* be exactly the word I need. But it's a highly-specialised usage that would normally be swamped by other connotations. So I'll upvote, but I don't think I'll be "accepting" this.

Answer (score 1):

[*Overemphasize*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overemphasize) — "to place too much emphasis on or employ too much emphasis".

That's what you did in your example at least.

Comment: But again this seems more akin to *overstate, overplay* - as if I've made too much of Factor X when trying to convince *other people*.

Comment: And OP has specifically listed and discounted this word in his question.

Comment: @Jim: Perhaps Chris thought I wouldn't notice because of the different spelling (luckily, I'm wise, not yet wizened! :)

Answer (score 1):

> I *exaggerated* the importance of X.
>     I *ennobled* X.
>   I *aggrandized* X.

Are some suggestions, if you want to avoid the over- prefix.

Comment: *ennobling* sounds a bit weird to me - but to me, the others imply defective presentation of an argument. I know in order to make a decision I have to "argue" with myself, but I want something implying *I **was fooled** [by myself]*, rather than *I **fooled** [anyone, perhaps myself]*